# x86 assembly language upper and lower bits

Tags: assembly, x86, bit

I am starting to learn x86 assembly language question that confuses me a great deal, it is as follows:

Given a 32-bit value we can swap its upper and lower 16 bits. For example, given

```
0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111
```

we can swap its upper and lower 16 bits to get the value

```
0100 0101 0110 0111 0000 0001 0010 0011
```

I know that the AX register contains the lower half of EAX but thats about it. Ay help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to do it? Just rotate by 16 bits, e.g. `rol eax, 16`.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question

Comment: The "lower" part is on the right, just like you write one hundred twenty three as "123" (toward right are positioned the lower powers of 10 till 10^0 ("ones") are reached). So to have the same direction with base 2 (binary) formatting, the "ones" are the last digit on right (also called "least significant bit", because it's just "one"). On left the first bit is of value 2^31. Mind you, this is just human visualization of bits, in the machine there's no left or right, they can be stored in any weird order the HW cells are designed, like interleaved, etc..

Answer (score 5):

> I know that the AX register contains the lower half of EAX but thats about it.

The `EAX` register is a 32-bit register and so it can hold your 32-bit value.
Its bits are numbered from 0 to 31.

This is how the bits are numbered:

```
0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111
^                 ^ ^                 ^ 
|                 | |                 bit 0
|                 | bit 15
|                bit 16
bit 31
```

The lower half of `EAX` occupies bits numbered from 0 to 15.
The upper half of `EAX` occupies bits numbered from 16 to 31.

The `AX` register is a 16-bit register that is situated in the lower half of the bigger `EAX` register. Its bits are numbered from 0 to 15.
The upper half of the `EAX` register has no separate name to go by!

Swapping the upper and lower 16 bits of `EAX` requires rotating the contents 16 times using:

```
rol eax, 16    ;Rotating to the left
```

The same value appears when using:

```
ror eax, 16    ;Rotating to the right
```

Answer (score 1):

I may not understand your question but what i can perceive is that you want to swap the upper and lower 16 bits of an EAX register, Right?
You can use the PTR operator in Assembly lang. Although PTR is mainly used when we want to work on a specific portion of a 32 bit register but we can use it to mov the value in a register and then work on it.
You can use ptr like this:

```
**.data**
myDouble DWORD 012345678h

**.code**
Mov AX, WORD PTR myValue         ; Loads 5678
Mov AX, WORD PTR myValue + 1     ; Loads 3456
```

Comment: You need `+2` to load the 2nd word.  Also, this doesn't ever produce a swapped dword in EAX; it first loads the low half, then replaces that with the 2nd and 3rd bytes.

Comment: Store/reload or multiple loads is not an efficient way to implement swapping.  You're sort of solving a related problem of just accessing part of a dword in memory.  (But use `movzx`.)